# Ports for Database Mirroring

Tags: sql-server-2005

Can we use same port for the principal,mirror and witness server? If yes what is the number?
Please let me know.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define your own custom port number for all three servers. They can all be the same unless you run the instances on the same physical server.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps start by reading: [Database Mirroring Setup Overview](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms365599.aspx)